# Cache annotation for a Mono return value no suitable serializer with Hazelcast

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, spring-webflux

Using spring-boot with spring-webflux and integrating with hazelcast 
an error occurs when trying to use the cache based on annotations.

I tried to use just spring-cache without hazelcast and works perfectly. but I should use hazelcast.

Maven dependencies

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

in a normal method when using the annotation Cachable

```
@Cacheable("ref-id")
public Mono<String> testCache(String testValue) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);  // (1)
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return Mono.just(testValue);
}
```

this error is thrown

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust'
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:75)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:157)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:133)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:118)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toData(AbstractSerializationService.java:106) 
.
.
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.serializerFor(AbstractSerializationService.java:487)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:146)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [CacheMono](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/blob/master/reactor-extra/src/main/java/reactor/cache/CacheMono.java) in the Reactor Add-ons.

The exception here is because Hazelcast can't find a way to serializable `Mono<T>`.
Everything you put in a Hazelcast cache must have some serialization mechanism, as the cache storage may potentially be on a remote JVM. [Mono](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.java) itself doesn't provide a mechanism.

`Mono<T>` for you means `Mono<String>`, serializing a String is built-in to Hazelcast so you don't need to worry about how that is done.